# How can I use theme functionality with JSS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jss

I've a problem to integrate the theming functionality inside my next.js project who use *react-jss*. I tried the ThemeProvider who I've found inside the documentation.
Everytime, my front-end page refresh two times. The first times, I can see that the CSS theme is apply but fews milliseconds later, the page refresh and the theme disappear. 
Do you have an idea to fix my problem? Here are my files:

**_document.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import {
    SheetsRegistry,
    JssProvider,
    ThemeProvider,
} from 'react-jss';

const theme = {
  colorPrimary: 'green',
};

export default class JssDocument extends Document {
  static getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const registry = new SheetsRegistry();
    const page = ctx.renderPage(App => props => (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <JssProvider registry={registry}>
          <App {...props} />
        </JssProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    ));

    return {
      ...page,
      registry,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <style id="server-side-styles">
            {this.props.registry.toString()}
          </style>
        </Head>

        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}
```

**index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import injectSheet from 'react-jss';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const styles = theme => ({
  myButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    color: theme.colorPrimary,
  },
});

const Index = ({ classes }) => (
  <div className={classes.myButton}>Welcome to Novatopo website!</div>
);

Index.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.shape({
    myButton: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
};

export default injectSheet(styles)(Index);
```

**_app.jsx**

```
import App from 'next/app';    
export default class MyApp extends App {
  componentDidMount() {
    const style = document.getElementById('server-side-styles');

    if (style) {
      style.parentNode.removeChild(style);
    }
  }
}
```

Here a CodeSandbox to reproduce the problem: [codesandbox.io/s/pyrznxkr1j](https://codesandbox.io/s/pyrznxkr1j)

Comment: My page is rendered two times. I think the theme style is apply during the server-side rendering process but it is immediately replace by the component style during the browser rendering. What are you feeling about that? How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score -1):

2 things you could do:

1. prepare a codesandbox example
2. use ThemeProvider inside of JssProvider

Comment: I switched ThemeProvider inside of JssProvider but nothing changes. I will prepare a codesandbox example, thanks.

Comment: Here my codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/pyrznxkr1j

Do you have an idea ? 

Answer (score -1):

I resolved the problem. You need to integrate the ThemeProvider logic inside the `_app.jsx` file.

Like that:

```
    export default class MyApp extends App {
        render() {
        const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

        return (
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </ThemeProvider>
        );
    }
}
```